# PHP SQLSRV - Query Not Working with ROW_NUMBER

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

My PHP version is 5.6.24, I'm using XAMPP, and I'm using this plugin : php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll.
My PHP project was working fine until just now, it showed some error when retrieving data.
[image: This is the Error]

This is the query that I tried to execute :

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY IsFlagLive DESC, NamaProyek ASC ) No , 
Id , NamaProyek , NamaPT , IPSite
FROM    dbo.MasterKolam
WHERE   RowStatus = 0
ORDER BY IsFlagLive DESC , NamaProyek ASC
```

I executed the query in SSMS, it worked fine.
I didn't change anything to the code or the query. I tried to remove the ROW_NUMBER part

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY IsFlagLive DESC, NamaProyek ASC ) No ,
```

It worked, but then I realized that many functions didn't work as well, so the issue is not only the ROW_NUMBER().

Is it something about T-SQL ? If yes, why my SQLSRV suddenly doesn't support it ? Is there any configuration for it ? Cheers.

(update) This is the script in PHP :

```
$str = "SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY IsFlagLive DESC, NamaProyek ASC) No, SELECT Id, NamaProyek,NamaPT,NamaDatabase,IdKuitansi,IsFlagLive,Logo,alamat,TlpNfax,SenderEmail,SenderPassword,IsPKP, ToBeApprove, ToBeApproveManager, IPSite FROM dbo.MasterKolam WHERE RowStatus = 0 ORDER BY IsFlagLive Desc, NamaProyek ASC";
$res = sqlsrv_query($KONEKSIMaster,$str,$params,$options);
$num = sqlsrv_num_rows($res);
```

Comment: Can you show us the actual query which is not working, and also mention what is dependent on it?  Obviously, if you remove a field it could break something.

Comment: Your error is in the PHP code and not the actual query. Show the php code for `servers.php`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have updated the question for the PHP Code

Comment: If you are using the procedural interface you need to check manually the return value of all functions involved and then call `sqlsrv_errors()` on error. Everything else is just a lottery.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the query which is not working is on the top of my question. I executed it in SSMS it worked fine but in SQLSRV it suddenly didn't work.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález sorry, I'm not familiar with sqlsrv_errors(). I added         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); below $num = sqlsrv_num_rows($res); but it didn't show anything

Comment: I'm not sure that the driver stores all error messages (I'd need to check it). To be safe, why don't you call it only after the statement that fails?

Comment: It look like you have not successfully connected to the database. `$KONEKSIMaster` is the offending variable. Show us the code that set this i.e. the code that connected to the database

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes, I did call it after the code that is error, which is sqlsrv_num_rows.... but thanks for your reference to sqlsrv_errors(), it might come useful for future use

Comment: @RiggsFolly the `$KONEKSIMaster` works fine. But well, I finally found the solution. Thanks !

Comment: No, `sqlsrv_num_rows()` does not even run because it's not receiving the result that `sqlsrv_query()` should produce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is all good now, guys. Apparently it is related to the disk space. I freed up some space (from ~2GB to ~9GB) and it works fine. Cheers !

Comment: I have to insist: if `sqlsrv_query()` fails for a reason like this, it will always return `false` and a subsequent call to `sqlsrv_errors()` should provide further details. Running database queries under the assumption that they can never fail is not realistic.